# how to store the scanned document in sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint document library and i want to store the scanned student records. And i have one custom column in my library called Student ID. when i was scanning the document it automatically stored the shared document but it didn't ask the Student ID. Can anybody have solution ?

Comment: i am using client object model in windows application

Comment: You can try using 'Callisto Managed Scan' which will directly store the scanned documents into SharePoint. It also provides feature to ask meta data while adding documents into SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Create a content type in the document library that has the student ID as a required field. Make that content type the default. When you upload a file to the document library, SharePoint will present the properties dialog, where all required fields for the content type need to be filled in before the file can be saved.

If you have check in /check out enabled on the library, you may be able to save the file without providing the metadata, but you will need to provide it when you check the file in.

Answer (score -1):

You can save yourself a lot of steps with Udocx form recognition if the student ID is on the document. After you press the 'scan' button it'll upload your documents to SharePoint and auto-fill the column.
Check the [Udocx website](http://www.udocx.com/SharePoint) for more information.

Comment: This can be solved using OOTB solutions.